# Does a hyperspace barrier still hinder travel to the Unknown Regions in the new canon?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

According to Wookieepedia regarding E.U./Legends, travel to and from the **[Unknown Regions](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Unknown_Regions)** is hindered by a **[hyperspace barrier](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hyperspace_disturbance_beyond_the_edge_of_the_galaxy)** (sometimes called "**the tangle**").

Being that **Starkiller Base** is in the *Unknown Regions* according to *The Force Awakens Visual Dictionary* and both the *Millennium Falcon* and Poe Dameron's Resistance squadron are able to successfully navigate it, does this hyperspace barrier still exist in the new canon?

If not, is there a reason given as to why the Unknown Regions haven't been explored yet?

Comment: hyperspace barrier sounds more like star trek than star wars. sure you dont confuse the two?

Answer (score 7):

Your question is somewhat based on a false premise regarding the Unknown Regions.

In Legends, there is considerable evidence that the unknown regions were... simply unexplored, rather than blocked. Grand Admiral Thrawn spent considerable effort/time exploring them and was in fact exiled there by the Chiss.

The book Outbook Flight even includes a smuggler ship jumping there blindly and encountering Thrawn, which is in Legends the explanation of how Thrawn knew basic.

This "hyperspace barrier" is not really something that exists in Legends/EU (though often there are references to the complexity of *charting* the Unknown Regions - perhaps this is what you are referring to?).

It is likely that for TFA this backstory was not incorporated and instead the Unknown Regions are simply uncharted space outside the jurisdiction of either the Empire or Republic.

Comment: According to *Star Wars: The Essential Atlas*, there are supposedly  hyperspace anomalies which hinder exploration of the **Unknown Regions**. (Ref: [Daniel Wallace's Geekosity: Endnotes for Star Wars: The Essential Atlas (part 1 of 5)](http://geekosity.blogspot.com/2009/08/endnotes-for-star-wars-essential-atlas.html)). Wookiepedia calls this barrier "the tangle" and says that it was an "impassable hyperspace barrier near the mid-line of the galaxy" which may have been created by the Celestials to curb the expansion of the Infinite Empire.